# mcopy, mformat, mattrib commands counterpart in windows?

Tags: cmd, sh

i am working on below given shell script, I found the solution from line 1 to line line 20 mentioned below. i need the windows optional commands for remaining commands of linux. e.g. mcopy, mformat, mattrib, can i use these commands in windows and if not then what are the windows counterpart of these commands.

```
#!/bin/sh   <--------------line 1
set -e
asm() {
nasm -o $2 $1
}
asm bios/dosbios.asm bios/dosbios.sys
asm boot/mboot.asm  boot/mboot.bin
asm util/format.asm util/format.com
asm util/fdisk.asm  util/fdisk.com
asm util/reboot.asm util/reboot.com
asm util/mem.asm    util/mem.com
asm util/attrib.asm util/attrib.com

#dd if=/dev/null of=dosbios.sys bs=512 seek=9

export MTOOLSRC=mtools.cfg

perl -e 'print chr(0xf6) x 2880 x 512' > 
disk/newdos.tmp
                          <-------- line 20
mformat -m 0xf8 -v DOS  a:
mcopy   bios/dosbios.sys a:io.sys
mcopy   msdos/msdos.sys a:
mcopy   msdos/*.com a:
mcopy   msdos/*.exe a:
mcopy   msdos1/*.com    a:

mcopy   util/*.com  a:
mcopy -a legal/*    a:
mcopy -a etc/*      a:

mattrib -a +s +h +r a:io.sys
mattrib -a +s +h +r a:msdos.sys

dd status=none if=boot/boot.com of=disk/newdos.tmp 
conv=notrunc
mv disk/newdos.tmp disk/newdos.img
```

my question is that can i use these commands in windows also, if not then what are the counterpart commands in windows.

Comment: `format`, `copy` and `attrib`. Note: how they work and what params they take may differ.

Comment: This is a pretty crazy question; these utilities exist *because* they duplicate MS-DOS commands with the same name, sans the leading `m`.